# 301 Redirect Conflict with www redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla, http-status-code-301

I am having an issue with my 301 redirects.

I just upgraded my site from an html based site to a joomla site. SO I am trying to redirect the 50 or so pages to the new joomla based navigation.

SO what is working:
rewrite rule to remove index.php, and the www., and 301 redirects

What isn't working:
301 redirect with a www in front of it.

```
www.sample.com/page.html
```

It sends them to the home page instead of the page, it takes them to the home page.

Here is my www rewrite rule.

```
## Redirects to www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.sample.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here is my 301 rule

```
Redirect 301 /page.html /page
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So for which URL it is not working?

Comment: You might edit to add clarity as-to how you want the page redirected... as that basically seems to say to do infinite redirects to itself for anything that comes to www.example.com/foo and www.example.com/foo (ie. semi redundant). BTW... you should use "example" rather than "sample" when sanitizing your configurations, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to remove the `www` then you might want to change the matching up some. Try your rule like this.

```
## Redirects to www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^page.html$ /page [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page2.html$ /page2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yeah that part works. The problem is when i have a www and a 301.

Comment: I tend to not mix my directives because of weird stuff that sometimes happens. You are already using the rewrite engine so why not just make rewrite rules instead of the weak redirect? See my edit for example.

Comment: 301 are for google. I was thinking along the same lines. is the r=301 the same as a 301 redirect?

Comment: 301 is a status code that means Moved Permanently, not just for Google. Yes the R flag stands for redirect with a status code of 301. so they are the same. Just another way to do it.